Google Apps script exceeds execution time without really triggering
Here's a rephrased version:
I have a script that runs every minute, but occasionally, about once a day, it fails with an "Exceeded maximum execution time" error.
To investigate the cause of the timeout, I added logging, including a log as the very first instruction in the main() function that gets triggered.
Surprisingly, this log isn't being recorded, and all I see in the logs is the execution time-out error occurring 6 minutes later.
Here's the function that gets triggered: (watchdog)
function main() {
  try {
    console.log("Triggered execution")
    checkIfRunning();
    haRunning();
  } catch (e) {
    notRunning(e);
  }
  
  console.info("Finished execution");
}

The first trace (triggered execution) is not in the logs for the timed-out trigger, there are 2 minutes gap between the previous and the next traces, unlike the rest where there exactly 1 minute.
Here is the error from the notification email:

Error message:
{
  "insertId": "voz23fe4o3o1",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "message": "Exceeded maximum execution time",
    "serviceContext": {
      "service": "<service id>"
    },
    "context": {
      "reportLocation": {
        "functionName": "[unknown function]",
        "filePath": "[unknown file]"
      }
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "app_script_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "195582552992",
      "function_name": "main",
      "invocation_type": "unknown"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-10-21T07:14:32.656Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "script.googleapis.com/deployment_id": "<deployment id>",
    "script.googleapis.com/process_id": "<long process id>",
    "script.googleapis.com/user_key": "<removed>",
    "script.googleapis.com/project_key": "<removed>"
  },
  "logName": "projects/project-id-<removed>/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-10-21T07:14:33.550483432Z",
  "errorGroups": [
    {
      "id": "CJDvpcPwjczqHA"
    }
  ]
}


It would be more helpful if the community can see at least the workflow of your code in a way that it highlights the complexity of the code(that may be causing the execution time out error)

Could you move the console.log outside the main?

@TheMaster you mean leave it as global call? Should it be called if the triggered function is main()?

Maybe just move the log part outside of try-catch block

@SagiLow Yes. A global call.

@TheMaster added, it doesn't show up on the timed-out missing trigger. It does show on other normal executions. Also tried moving the first log outside the try/catch as per 4thAnd1 suggestion but it's all the same

@4thAnd1 see comment, no change even after moving the first log outside the try/catch

This should go as a bug report in the issuetracker. There isn't much we can do here.  See tag info page for links to the tracker.
